# Is there a minimum period for the bright-line property rule in New Zealand?

Tags: capital-gains, tax

In New Zealand, there is a law for capital gains tax called [the bright-line property rule](https://www.ird.govt.nz/property/buying-and-selling/when-you-need-to-pay/the-brightline-property-rule):

> If you sell a residential property you have owned for less than 10 years you may have to pay income tax on any gain on the sale, unless an exclusion or rollover relief applies. This is the bright-line property rule and it also applies to New Zealand tax residents who buy overseas residential properties.

I have reason to believe that there is a minimum period for this, or a real estate agent is excluded from it.  I can't find this on the IRD's (Inland Revenue Department) web site.

This is just for interest's sake but is based on a real event that has happened.  We sold one of our rental properties.  The buyer was a Real Estate Agent, and he sold it (before he bought it form us) to another property dealer.  Who in turn had sold it before we received any money, to the final purchaser.

I can't do anything about, nor do I intend to.  It is what it is.  However, I can't imagine both of these intermediate entities paying Capital Gains Tax.  **Is there a minimum period, or does a negative period count as no period?**

Comment: Why can't you imagine both entities paying tax?  If both entities managed to quickly flip the property at a profit, I can't imagine either being unhappy to pay taxes on that profit.

Comment: https://www.ird.govt.nz/property/buying-and-selling/when-you-need-to-pay/the-brightline-property-rule

Comment: @Greendrake, as mentioned, I have already read that.  I am asking, does zero days or negative days bypass it.

Comment: @JustinCave, perhaps real estate agents are respected better in your country.  Here they are despised and rank just above used car salesmen, as so many are dodgy.  I have no doubt whatsoever, that they have found a loophole.  :-)

Comment: @JustinCave.    To expand, they had very dodgy and cheeky clauses that the had sneaked in to the standard real estate contract (in NZ).  I kept removing them and they kept inserting new ones.  For example, they wanted to show their buyers through the house, before having possession.  Then they wanted to move their furniture in (to style it), before possession.  Except that may have legally counted as possession.  We needed to sell  urgently, or we would have asked them to go somewhere.

Comment: It sounds like they were make sure they could use the money from the ultimate buyer to pay you rather than putting any of their own money at risk rather than finding a loophole  that allows them to avoid being taxed on their gains.  You may find it dodgy that they take advantage of a motivated seller and profit without putting any of their own capital at risk.

Comment: What makes you think that the agent does not pay tax on the difference?

Comment: Usually, the tax laws imposes taxes on short flip transactions at higher rates. I've never seen any tax law that exempts such transaction. Your distrust of realtors isn't any reason to change that assessment. If anything, it makes it less likely that they'd get a tax break.

Answer (score 1):

### New Zealand does not have a [capital gains tax](https://taxsummaries.pwc.com/new-zealand/individual/income-determination#:%7E:text=New%20Zealand%20does%20not%20have,the%20definition%20of%20%27income%27.)

However, various forms of gain are treated as income and are taxed accordingly. One of these is where the taxpayer deals in such property, which would undoubtedly captures both buyers/sellers in the chain you describe. Their gain will be part of their income, and they will pay tax on it.